# Disallow VNC if not via a SSH tunnel?

Tags: ssh, vnc

How can I disallow VNC if the connection isn't via a SSH tunnel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's not explicitly listed as an option to `vnc4server`, you should be able to pass the `-localhost` option to the underlying `Xvnc` process.

From `man vncserver`:

```
   You can add Xvnc options at the command line. They will be added to the
   invocation of Xvnc without changes.
```

From `man Xvnc`:

```
   -localhost
          Only  allow connections from the same machine. Useful if you use
          SSH and want to stop non-SSH connections from any  other  hosts.
          See the guide to using VNC with SSH on the web site.
```

Alternatively, you could use `ufw` or `iptables` to default deny external connections, only opening the chosen SSH port.